# "Clockwiseality" and Chirality

Tags: terminology

This question was asked over on ELU https://english.stackexchange.com/q/287021/129806.

It seems most people agree that "chirality" is the correct word to use, however I am not so sure.  I feel this question is best addressed in a more rigorous way, so I am linking it over here.

It seems that the question is mixing direction of motion with "handedness" and that the correct way to talk about the symbol is its orientation.  The only reason "clockwise" makes any sense is the idea that the arms on the symbol look like motion lines from a cartoon, so the mind fills in the idea of "clockwise" or "anticlockwise."

What's the best way to talk about this situation?

Comment: Chirality often refers to orientations in 3d, but the question is about orientations in 2d. I don't think it's a big deal either way.

Comment: I'd go with "orientation."